# Ajax Event Listener and Google Analytics

Tags: ajax, google-analytics

I've implemented the script found on this site
http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/08/27/ajax-event-listener-google-tag-manager/ to this website http://www.clubmansfield.ca.

However, when a form is filled, it is firing 3 events in GA, which is making accurate tracking difficult.  Can anyone tell me why that is or how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you perhaps attempt to figure out what's going on, and provide some code that you think may be the issue?

Comment: I'm not a coder, which is why I'm asking the experts here.  I thought it could be something in the source code from the LunaMetrics post, but I haven't seen anyone else post that issue.

Comment: There's not enough information here. I filled out a form, but saw nothing firing. Can you post screenshots at least of the error, the 3 events... your cat (just kidding)....

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated to know why the code is firing 3 times, i checked the domain and i cant found that implementation. the most possible cause is that you add 3 trigger rules on the tag, if that is the case, remember that the selected trigger have the or condition, not the and , and every condition is analized one by one